# How do I set up permissions in django-rest-framework so that the session user can only list objects which have a foreign key to that user?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have models like this:

```
class TheModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

I'd like to create an API view which lists all of `TheModel` objects wherein `TheModel.owner` equals `request.user`.

I think I can do this by overriding `get_queryset`, but it seems like I should be using a custom `BasePermission`.  The problem is that it doesn't look like `BasePermission.has_object_permission` is run on each object in a list view. The only thing that gets run is `BasePermission.has_permission`. I tested this with this :-

```
class TheModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = TheModel
    permission_classes = [IsOwner]

class IsOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        print("checking has permission for {}".format(request.user))
        return True

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        print("checking permission for {} on {}").format(request.user, obj.user)

        return obj.owner == request.user
```

The only thing that gets printed is the stuff from `IsOwner.has_permission`.

Maybe I'm just over thinking it and I should just be using custom querysets instead of using permissions?

Comment: You're essentially relying on the client to authenticate itself in this case. Permissions in (most) databases aren't at the entry level, they're at the table level, and they're really only designed to allow you to give differing permissions to database administrators. If you really want to implement a per-entry permissions scheme, you need to have a *server* that's between the *client* and the database that performs the authentication check to the client's *request* and then returns a *response*. Any instance where the client has direct access to the database is NOT secure.

Comment: @aruisdante Imagine a web app that lets say...people with a lawn cutting business...manage their clients.  We have a db model, CuttingClient.  Different lawn cutting people using the web app shouldn't have access to the clients of other lawn cutting people.  What other type of scheme than a per-entry permissions scheme would work?

Comment: @aruisdante Additionally, Django manages the user authentication for sessions.  In what case would a user be able to masquerade as another user?  In what way is that not secure?

Comment: @aruisdante In this case there is already a _server_ between the _client_ and the database... this is the web server, the one that is running the Django code in the OP's question. So the first part if your comment "You're essentially relying on the client to authenticate itself in this case" is false, but the rest is correct in principle. In fact the code the OP posted is exactly what you have stipulated needs to exist.

Comment: @Anentropic sure absolutely if this code is not on the client machine. If this is server-side code for a web front-end, then yeah, that's fine, and I misread the OP's question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [official documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets#modelviewset) recommends using a custom `get_queryset` method in this use-case, and that's exactly what I would do.

The permission object's `has_object_permission` only runs when called on a view for a single object, so that won't work to enforce permissions for list views.

Basically, you are not trying to allow or deny access, you are trying to filter the results. Filtering on a database level is the fastest, easiest and most secure (least error-prone) option. The permission framework is only made to either allow or deny access to an object or a complete object group, it is not made to filter the content of a particular response. The `get_queryset` method is made to filter the content of a particular response, and should be used as such.