# Database per-row permissions for a web application OK to do?

Tags: django, database-design

A [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23447157/how-do-i-set-up-permissions-in-django-rest-framework-so-that-the-session-user-ca#comment35939980_23447157) on another question of mine has me worrying about how I have my Django application built, especially as I couldn't get any response to my follow-up comments.

So, to summarize:  I have a table of `Things` with a foreign key to `Users`.  These are Django users, so I check `request.user` against `Things.owner` in my views.

Is this an OK way to handle a bunch of users having their own `Things`?

Is there a better way to handle it?

Is the comment I link to just wrong or not applicable to this use-case?

Comment: the comment is wrong, this is how it's usually done

Comment: I think you misunderstood the comment. He's talking about permissions in the database. You can't have per-row permissions in the database itself without an intermediary server that authorizes requests and filters results. In the case of django-rest-framework, Django _is_ the intermediary server. You rely on Django (the client of the sql server) to authenticate itself.

Comment: I don't think he misunderstood the comment, the commenter misunderstood the context of Django code.

Comment: @Anentropic Both, as he's clearly talking about permissions at the database level. But the commenter's misunderstanding probably caused the confusion in the first place.

Comment: @knbk the commenter is the only one talking about permissions at the database level, which are basically irrelevant to what the OP was asking

Comment: @Anentropic Now that's exactly what I'm saying, isn't it? :P

Comment: @Anentropic is correct.  I understood that the comment on the other post was talking about database level permissions.  What I didn't understand was how that was relevant to my question.

Comment: It's not, as Django serves as a server between the user and the database. The comment is not wrong, it's just irrelevant to Django.